# Onenote API for Local Computer

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

This is my first post on Stackoverflow - I am looking for guidance about OneNote API. I look forward to develop a solution primarily for "Own Usage" - which Creates, Opens and Closes OneNote Sections on my Local Machine - No cloud etc. is to be used. Please guide if it will be possible?

I hope it should be possible - Please guide how to proceed and what to study for that. My programming skills are very basic.

I will prefer to use OneNote 2007.

[Edit on 5th Nov. Noon IST] A few clarifications might help: I had initially gone through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn575425.aspx however, I found that "The OneNote API runs on the Microsoft globally-available cloud, and sends data from your app into the user's OneDrive". Whereas in my case no other user or cloud is to be involved. I wish to "develop a solution primarily for "Own Usage" - which Creates, Opens and Closes OneNote Sections on my Local Machine". It seems that a link suggested by "Sebov1c" msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj680118.aspx and another suggested by "Jorge Aguirre" should serve my purpose. I will do my homework on this topic over the next week and get back here.

Thanks and Regards

Sanjiv

Comment: Please read [ask] - generally the MS Office API is documented well enough, so you should be able to do some research prior to posting here. If you encounter a *specific* programming problem, you are welcome to ask.

Comment: "No cloud etc. is to be used" - what exactly does that mean? The OneNote API is for accessing OneNote notes/pages in the cloud.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that the OneNote REST API is for cloud based notebooks only, so I don't think that's an option for you.

If you want offline support on windows only, your other option is to use the OneNote interop C# libraries (from what you say, I think this is what you're looking for) There's a pretty good example here:
[How To Write To A OneNote 2013 Page Using C# and The OneNote Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294510/how-to-write-to-a-onenote-2013-page-using-c-sharp-and-the-onenote-interop)

There's other options to write apps that are embedded in OneNote, but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

There is a COM API for OneNote.  Check out a sample here: http://www.github.com/OneNoteDev/VanillaAddin