# Is it necessary to have business account for use OneNote API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I am developing an application using Microsoft Graph and I am testing some basic features with OneNote. I can use the users, but I'm getting errors regarding SharePoint licenses when it comes to OneNote.

Error that i am receiving:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "30121",
    "message": "The tenant does not have a valid SharePoint license.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "12d9555f-ab42-43d6-a5ad-ed4be2fe0c93",
      "date": "2019-11-11T12:58:55"
    }
  }
}

Do I need to buy Office of Business if I already have Office for Home, and if no how do I solve this error?

According to [Calendar endpoint returns OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347728/microsoft-graph-api-calendar-endpoint-returns-organizationfromtenantguidnotfou), I need to have an Office 365 Business subscription, but it still not clear for me why it should include SharePoint.

This is the code which I am running:

```cs
public class X
{
    public void thing()
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task<string> task = GetAccessToken();
            task.Wait();

            var token = task.Result;
            Console.WriteLine(token);

            Task<string> usersTask = GetUser(token);
            usersTask.Wait();

            var user = usersTask.Result;
            Console.WriteLine(user);

            Task<string> notesTask = GetNotes(token, user); //GetEmail(token, user);
            notesTask.Wait();

            var notes = notesTask.Result;
            Console.WriteLine(notes);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
        {
            string token = "";
            StringContent content =
                new StringContent($"client_id={clientId}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret={appKey}&grant_type=client_credentials", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            using(var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token", content))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    token = result.access_token;
                }
            }

            return token;
        }

        static async Task<string> GetUser(string token)
        {
            string user = "";
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            using(var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    dynamic users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
                    return users.value[1].id;
                }
            }

            return user;
        }

        static async Task<string> GetNotes(string token, string userId)
        {
            var data = "";
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            using(var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/onenote/notebooks"))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) //error
                {
                    var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return res;
                }
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're showing the code you're using to call the API but not the response you're getting back. OneNote APIs support both Work and Personal accounts but without seeing the response it is pretty difficult to diagnose.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur,{
  "error": {
    "code": "30121",
    "message": "The tenant does not have a valid SharePoint license.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "10f50974-e056-4feb-b9aa-4ca99a02d10e",
      "date": "2019-11-11T12:51:56"
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to access cloud based information/notebooks, you'll need an [Office 365 subscription](https://products.office.com/).

OneNote Notebooks are stored on Sharepoint in Office 365.

There's also the option to use the [Interop C# assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421115/onenote-api-for-local-computer)...