# Using the One note API to save data from a Winform applciation on a Microsoft account

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, onenote, onenote-api

I am writing a ToDo list Winform application and I would like to use the the One Note API in order to save the information about the tasks in the user Microsoft account.

So I browsed the One Note API documentation but after a few hours of research I did not manage to find a good entry point.

I understand that the first step for me would be to sign the user which is described on this page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826543.aspx

The thing is that the different ways of achieving that step don't seem suitable for a Winform client application, maybe I should use the rest API ?

I have been looking for a .NET code example but have yet to find any so I'm quite confused right now...

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Yes, you should try Rest API for this purpose..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the OneNote API - signing in can be achieved by using a webcontrol and having the user follow the sign in flow there. Unfortunately we don't have any sample code for winforms, but the auth flow in our NodeJs sample for the OneNote API should be similar.
https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleNodejs

You could also (assumming the user has OneNote installed) use the OneNote interop libraries to interact with OneNote and store/retrieve your data there.
[How To Write To A OneNote 2013 Page Using C# and The OneNote Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294510/how-to-write-to-a-onenote-2013-page-using-c-sharp-and-the-onenote-interop)

You might also want to try developing a universal app instead of a windows forms application:
https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleWinUniversal