# Writing HTML to OneNote C#

Tags: c#, html, onenote, onenote-api

I am trying to write HTML contents to OneNote. What I'm trying to do is get the contents of a word file that is written in html and write that html to OneNote to successfully convert all elements of that page to OneNote. Here is what I have for converting the word document to HTML:

```
    public static void convertWordToHtml()
    {
        byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("GreetingFile2.docx");
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            memoryStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
            {
                HtmlConverterSettings settings = new HtmlConverterSettings()
                {
                    PageTitle = "My Page Title"
                };
                XElement html = HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(doc, settings);

                File.WriteAllText("‪Something.html", html.ToStringNewLineOnAttributes());
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the code I have for writing content to OneNote programmatically.

```
static Application onenoteApp = new Application();
static XNamespace ns = null;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    GetNamespace();
    string notebookId = GetObjectId(null, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsNotebooks, "Aaron @ Microsoft");
    string sectionId = GetObjectId(notebookId, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsSections, "New Section 1");
    string firstPageId = GetObjectId(sectionId, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsPages, "My Page");
    GetPageContent(firstPageId);
    Console.Read();
}

static void GetNamespace()
{
    string xml;

    onenoteApp.GetHierarchy(null, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsNotebooks, out xml);
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    ns = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;
}

static string GetObjectId(string parentId, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope scope, string objectName)
{
    string xml;
    onenoteApp.GetHierarchy(parentId, scope, out xml);

    var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var nodeName = "";

    switch(scope)
    {
        case (Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsNotebooks): nodeName = "Notebook"; break;
        case (Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsPages): nodeName = "Page"; break;
        case (Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsSections): nodeName = "Section"; break;
        default:
            return null;
    }

    var node = doc.Descendants(ns + nodeName).Where(n => n.Attribute("name").Value == objectName).FirstOrDefault();

    return node.Attribute("ID").Value;
}

static string GetPageContent(string pageId)
{
    string xml;
    onenoteApp.GetPageContent(pageId, out xml, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.PageInfo.piAll);
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var outline = doc.Descendants(ns + "Outline").First();
    var content = outline.Descendants(ns + "T").First();
    string contentVal = content.Value;
    content.Value = "Modified something cool";
    onenoteApp.UpdatePageContent(doc.ToString());
    return null;
}
```

Is there a way I can write the HTML I've gotten to OneNote? I have tried the OneNote API but that hasn't been working to well for me because setting it up has been a bit difficult to understand.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this? Edit new details into your original post, not a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760298/inserting-html-into-onenote

Comment: yes but I updated my code because I've made further progress. The answer didn't specify how to actually write the HTML to OneNote.