# Opening new OneNote Notebook and Section via VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, onenote

It is possible to opening new onenote notebook and section via VB.NET? I was searching for all this time but never found the match result. Does anyone know the code?

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj680120.aspx
[How To Write To A OneNote 2013 Page Using C# and The OneNote Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294510/how-to-write-to-a-onenote-2013-page-using-c-sharp-and-the-onenote-interop)

I believe the OneNote Interop APIs is what you want.

Comment: Thanks before, but i was searching for visual basic language. Is that just for C#?

Comment: Oh! Thanks then :)